# Building applications using multiple datasources for single objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm struggling finding a right solution for my application architecture. For my application I have a single class for customers. The data for filling my customer objects are spread over multiple different types of datasources. The main part is exposed in a readonly Oracle database, other parts are exposed using a webservices and I need te save some extra data to another datasource (for instance a MS SQL database using entityframework) since I only have readonly rights for most datasouces (they are managed somewhere else).

For this reason I wanna build some kind of central library with connectors to all of my datasources for creating a centralized Customer Object to work with. So far so good for this idea (I think) but I can't find any documentation or example with best practices how to achieve such a solution.

```
EXAMPLE:
  * Main Application (multiple applications)
     - Central Business Logic Layer (Business-API)
         * Webservice Connector
         * Oracle Connector
         * EntityFramework Connector
```

Does anyone know if there is some good reading material on this specific subject?

Kind regards

Comment: Couldn't you just implement the IRepository pattern where the GET returns your model of collective data from each database context?

Comment: I agree with @JacobRoberts - the best way to go would be to implement the repository pattern for the different data sources. Be sure to read this first though http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you describe with *customer objects* sounds a lot like the one solved by the [Data Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), which is technically a kind of [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Quoting from the [Wikipedia page for Data Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern):

> A Data Mapper is a Data Access Layer that performs bidirectional transfer of data between a persistent data store (often a relational database) and an in memory data representation (the domain layer). The goal of the pattern is to keep the in memory representation and the persistent data store independent of each other and the data mapper itself. The layer is composed of one or more mappers (or Data Access Objects), performing the data transfer. Mapper implementations vary in scope. Generic mappers will handle many different domain entity types, dedicated mappers will handle one or a few.

Although the language of the problem above speaks of a *persistent data store* that's singular, there's no reason why it couldn't be several data locations (Mediator pattern hides the details from the collaborators).

There is an extension of this pattern, known as the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the DAO-Pattern to abstract from any data access. The business logic should not be aware of any datasources. This is the most important aim. Anything else has to be subordinated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor that accepts datasources like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(OracleConnector oracle, WebSerivceConnector webservice, EntityConnector entity)
    {
        this.oracle = oracle;
        this.webservice = webservice;
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public void Fetch()
    {
        // fetch data from oracle, webservice, and entity.
        this.Name = oracle.GetCustomerName();
    }
}
```

This way only `Customer` knows how to get the data, all the logic is in one place. You can even make it more testable and less coupling by creating interfaces for connectors.

```
public interface IOracleConnector
{
    // add something here
    string GetCustomerName();
}

public class OracleConnector
    : IOracleConnector
{
    // add the implementation here.
}
```

Then change `Customer` constructor to accepts `IOracleConnector` like:

```
public Customer(IOracleConnector oracle, WebSerivceConnector webservice, EntityConnector entity)
{
    // your code here.
}
```

Now, you can create a mock to test `Customer` without actually connecting to the database.

Comment: Do I see a business object that knows about technology (WebService) or even a product (Oracle)? You should not mix different abstraction levels.

Comment: `IOracleConnector` is just an interface, so Customer only knows about the contracts defined in it. If the OP plans to change the storage engine in the future he can create a new class that implements `IOracleConnector` like `WhateverConnector` and `Customer` will continue to work.